# Run script in wkhtmltopdf process

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf to create pdf(s) from html(s)

I have next function :

```
private void CreateTempPdf(string htmlPath, string pdfPathTemp)
        {
            var processorInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                                {
                                    Arguments =
                                        "--margin-top 27 \"" + htmlPath + "\" \"" + pdfPathTemp +
                                        "\" ",
                                    FileName = PublisherConfigurationManager.Pdf2HtmlConverter,
                                    UseShellExecute = true
                                };

            using (var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = processorInfo;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
```

in which i pass paths of html file and destination file.

I want to add some js script to run, before pdf will be generated.

I add my code : `--run-script <js>` into `Arguments` after `pdfPathTemp` but script isn't applied to pdf. I also add it before `--margin` but this case also doesn't help me.

How correctly add scripts into wkhtmltopdf process?

Comment: Why not use wrappers like TuesPechkin?

Comment: @rajeemcariazo, thanks for advice... maybe later... now just wkhtmltopdf  :(

Comment: Can you please post your answer how you did it?

Comment: @ChetanOswal probably it was like that `--run-script <js>` It was a long time ago.. and cannot remember now for sure

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add the script directly into the HTML page. In this case I would load the HTML from the path into a string, inject the script, then write a tempfile for the process duration.

As for why --run-script does not work, I have no idea. Have you tried it directly in the command line with a very simple script and HTML to see if a minimal example works for you?

If that is not an option, you might have to play around with different files for differnt js arguments, if you require such things.

Comment: thanks for reply. But can you write how to use --run-script correctly? Like `--run-script <js>` and then source html and destination pdf file?

Comment: @demo Yeah, afaik it's just just like that.

Comment: ok, thanks, yes, my script works, but i does work something strange